What polls, if any, exist regarding public opinion towards media controls in Iran?
The Iranian government is known to have strict controls on the media in the country, both journalistic and popular. However, how popular is this in Iran? Independent polling in Iran can be difficult, and though I have been able to find polls on issues such as support for mandatory versus voluntary hijab usage, presidential approval, referenda and even drug use, I have not found any polling about this. Does such polling exist, and if so, what does it indicate?
Note that I am not looking for answers regarding whether Iranian policy in this regard is positive or negative, just information on public opinion polling. Nonetheless, answers relying on informal polling from people who live in Iran are welcome in the absence of statistical studies.

What makes you think a theocracy would want a poll carried out on their particular religious strictures?  That sounds like asking for trouble, best to claim everyone sees the wisdom inherent in such noble endeavors.

@ItalianPhilosopher - There have been polls on a lot of things in Iran. They may not be common, but they exist. E.g. polls on mandatory hijab usage, another religious stricture. So it is not inconceivable that there was polling on this.

I did not realize that, much surprised.

@ItalianPhilosopher - I am a bit surprised not to have any responses from the handful of Iranian contributors here, though. I added that last line specifically so that they could share their impressions of people's views in environment in which they live, even in the absence of formal surveys.

If they're not published in English on the internet, it doesn't mean that they don't exist!

A survey on public opinion regarding the “necessity of wearing a hijab in public places” indicates that 84.3% of respondents (both men and women) agree with the social requirement of wearing a hijab. The agreement among “women” is higher, at 86.5%. However, the perception of this requirement varies among these individuals, ranging from legal enforcement to cultural and moral obligation.

While a portion of society believes in legal enforcement of hijab and sees a role for the government (46%), another group, in addition to considering the hijab obligatory in public, agrees with a cultural approach to this requirement (49%). Published a year ago.

@Anonymous - That is roughly in line with this study or that might even be the one you are talking about. However, I was aware of the existence of studies on hijab mandates and was asking about opinion on media controls. Can you find any similar surveys for media controls?

What "media control"? When the US bans TikTok for national security, it's a good thing, when it comes to Iran, it becomes "media control"? Iran never blocked the platforms like Instagram or Twitter to control the flow of information, they blocked them because they were violating Iran's sovereignty and challenging its national security.

The majority of respondents (62.5%) are against the filtering of Instagram. In contrast, 14.8% of respondents are in favor of filtering Instagram. These proportions are 84.4% and 10%, respectively, among Instagram users. There are many I don't find them at the moment, the issue is not lack of polling, the matter is the intention and the statistical population.

During the recent presidential election, there were much polling institutes that did the job and their projections and polling came true finally.

@Anonymous - No, the proposed TikTok ban in the USA is also a kind of media control. It's evident from the plain meaning of the word, which I chose to avoid the negative connotations of "censorship" and get more objective answers rather than simple criticism of Iranian government policies. It is also questionable whether the USA is really motivated by "national security" in blocking TikTok, much as it is questionable whether Iran is.

@Anonymous - Anyway, it seems as if you have some polling about controls on at least one kind of social media, which seems like either a good answer or the beginning of a good answer. Could you write one?
